# How to view method information in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-view

In Eclipse, when you hover your mouse over a method, a window would appear with a description of what the method does, what the parameters mean and what it returns. Is there a way to get Android Studio to do the same thing?

Comment: There is a faster, much more convenient approach. Just press ctrl + space (Mac OS X) when your cursor is over a method. It will open up a small dialog window with the documentations.

Comment: Ctrl+Q is the way to go.

Comment: On Catalina (at least) ⌘ + SPACE is reserved for the system's Spotlight Search.
However, ⌥ + SPACE works fine

Answer (score 959, accepted):

The easiest and the most straightforward way:

To activate: menu *File* → *Settings* → *Editor* → *General*

For Mac OS X, *Android Studio* → *Preferences* → *Editor* → *General* and check *Show quick documentation on mouse move*:

[image: Settings dialog with checked option]

---

Other ways:

- You can go into your [IntelliJ IDEA's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) *bin* folder and search for **idea.properties**. Add this line to the document:

  `auto.show.quick.doc=true`

Now you'll have the same floating documentation window like in [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29).

- You have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to see the Javadoc.

You can pin the window and make the documentation appear every time you select a method with your mouse though.

[image]

**Android Studio 1.0:** You have to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> if you want to get hold of the documentation window, for example, scrolling documentation. Otherwise, as you move your mouse away from the method, the documentation window will disappear.

Comment: The CTRL+Q alternative for OS X users is F1.

Comment: In Android Studio 0.8 "Preferences" is actually File->Settings

Comment: +1 for mentioning to hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. It is really annoying to see the window is gone when mouse is moving. Previously I dock the window. Now I can use the quick floating window again. Great.

Comment: In Android Studio 4.1, it is now under `Code Editing`.
OSX: Preferences > Code Editing > Quick Documentation

Answer (score 125):

Yes, you can. Go to menu *File* → *Settings* → *Editor* → *Show quick documentation on mouse move*

Or, in Mac OS X, go to Android Studio → *Preferences* → *Editor* → *General* → *Show quick doc on mouse move*.

Answer (score 32):

It comes very handy if you create a keymap for functionalities you use very frequently. By default (if you select an [OS X v10.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) (Leopard) and later keymap):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>: To see what parameters are expected by the function
2. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>: To see the documentation
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>: To see the autocomplete suggestions

[image]

Comment: Now in Android Studio Chipmunk, command + J is the key. Previous releases it was other combination :c

Answer (score 20):

In addition to the answers here, you might want to make sure that the documentation is downloaded. To do that, go to *SDK Manager*:

[image]

And then the *SDK Tools* tab and make sure *Documentation for Android SDK* is installed.

[image]

If it isn't, check the box and click <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

Answer (score 16):

**Android Studio 2.x.x** 
Moved under menu *Editor* → *General*

[image]

#### Older Versions

Using Windows 7 and Android Studio 1.0.x it took me a while to figure out the steps provided in the answer.

To help further visitors save some time, here is the way I did it:

Go to menu *File* → *Settings* or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

The following window will open and check *Show quick doc on mouse move* under *IDE Settings* → *Editor*.

[image: Show quick doc]

Or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hover your move over your method, class, etc.

Answer (score 14):

If you just need a shortcut, then it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> on Linux (and Windows).
Just hover the mouse on the method and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to see the doc.

Answer (score 12):

> If you need only Parameter info then:

On Mac, it's assigned to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

On Windows, it's assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

> If you need document info then:

On Mac, it's assigned to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

On Windows, it's assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Comment: What about on Linux?

Comment: Command+Q on Mac shuts down Android Studio lol. Ctrl+J is the shortcut for quick documentation.

Comment: Works for Windows

Answer (score 7):

Go to *Editor* → *Preference* → *Editor* → *General*
and choose *Show quick doc on mouse hover*!

[image]

Answer (score 7):

On Mac the default key combination for showing the quick documentation is: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

The cursor has to be on the method when using this.

Answer (score 7):

On my Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> stopped working, but <kbd>F1</kbd> on its own works.

Answer (score 6):

For Android Studio **4.1** and **4.2**, this checkbox has moved under *Editor* → *General* → *Code Completion*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Many of the other answers are all well, but if you want an informational tooltip instead of a full-blown window then do this: after enabling it using [Ahmad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619667/how-to-view-method-information-in-android-studio/16619709#16619709) then click on the little pin on the upper right corner:

[image]

After this the method information will appear on a tooltip like almost every other mainstream IDE.

Answer (score 2):

MacBook: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> does the same.

Also, use the one from the editor definition as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS:

*Preferences -> Editor -> Code Editing -> Quick Documentation -> Show quick documentation on hover*

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio too much and I want to see parameters when I click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. That's why I'm using Visual Studio keys.

To change the keymap to the Visual Studio keymap:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the information I've organized from each answer. Thanks to everyone for their contributions.

### Quick Documentation Lookup (Show documentation on hover)

> Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> (macOS: <kbd>Command + J</kbd>)
>
> [image]
>
> ##### setting:
>
> - Disable support for screen readers
>
> > `Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Support screen readers`
> >
> > [image]
>
> - Tooltip delay time
>
> > Set a reasonable delay time
> >
> > `Editor > Code Editing > Tooltip delay`
> >
> > [image]

### Documentation popup on the right side of usage

> [image]
>
> ##### setting:
>
> `Editor > Code Completion > Show the documentation popup`
>
> [image]

### Parameter info

> Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd>
>
> [image]

### Display basic code completion

> Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>
> (Windows might conflict with some language input methods, switch to full English)
>
> [image]

### Insert Live Template

> Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

refer to the official JetBrains standard shortcuts at:
https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf