# Android studio breadcrumb method signature

Tags: android-studio, breadcrumbs, method-signature

I am looking for Breadcrumb functionality like Eclipse in Android Studio.

In Eclipse Breadcrumb shows "method signature" when pointer(cursor) come inside whereas in Android Studio Breadcrumb is good for nothing.

Please find attached for better insight.

[image]

Comment: I need this as well.. how to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems this feature gone away.
You should use:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> **OR** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: I am using Eclipse key mapping in Android Studio, Ctrl+F12 is not working at my end.

Comment: .@AVEbrahimi as I told I am using Eclipse mapping and I found Ctrl+F3/Ctrl+O do a trick i.e "File Structure" thanks!

Comment: @AmitYadav Well, don't you think you should be educating yourself by following the Android Studio UI designers into their world? Every tool has it's pros and cons, so by setting wrapping Android Studio into a half working Eclipse keys UI you are definitively loosing that other half that Android Studio had prepared for you...

Comment: You should write function name, not shortcut name, which may differ.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is not correct.

The feature is still here in 2018.

It's under **View** -> **Active Editor** -> **Show Breadcrums**.

The breadcrums are situated south of the current editing window, not north as in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you.  I missed "south of the current editing window,".  It used to be north.

Comment: after 3 years i come back to the answer to thank myself - i forgot where they hid this valuable option :D also, thank you guys for up-voting this answer! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can enable it via View -> Navigation Bar and check it.

But it will show breadcrumb/navigation upto class only and not upto the method signature.

As suggessted by  AVEbrahimi also, ctrl+F12 will show method signature.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to see the method signature through a tool tip that hovers next to the method you have selected or put the caret on.

Press **ctrl + P** with the method selected.

or

Go to **View > Show Parameter Info** with the method selected.

I found the above solution on the second link I looked at after this one. The link was for a different IDE but the hotkey works in Android Studio.

[Show Parameter Info](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/viewing-method-parameter-information.html)

Also, you can go to **Settings > Editor** 
Under "**Other**" check "**Show quick doc on mouse move**". This will show a popup tool tip with information about the method including parameter info.

Found that here:

[View method information in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619667/view-method-information-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> displays the name of the current context, which is actually the method name (Context Info) quickly and easily.