# See the information about some API method/API object ( like on MSDN ) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am looking for something like *Microsoft* have on their *MSDN* that can give me information on any object/method on the standard Android API.

Is there something like that on *Android Studio*?

Comment: MSDN  is different from Visual Stuido. If you want to access documentation either https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html (or) download above documentation to your local and access it.

Comment: so, there is an option to access documentation on android studio ( maybe offline also ) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View method information in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619667/view-method-information-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut in Android Studio to see Javadoc info. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619667/view-method-information-in-android-studio).