# Show Android Studio full method description

Tags: android, methods

I have an issue that's driving me nuts.

When I hit the shortcut to see the method descriptions, I only get to see method signature. How can I see the full blown description I see online?

This is what I see on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>:

[image]

This is what I want to see and what's at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)

[image]

By the way, I just checked off the setting to enable the quick information when I hover the mouse over; however, the problem is not that it doesn't work, but rather that it is not the full description. I think I'm missing documentation.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View method information in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619667/view-method-information-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this, from this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619667/view-method-information-in-android-studio) -

The easiest and the most straightforward way:

You can activate it by going to: File > Settings > Editor > General and check Show quick documentation on mouse move.

[image]

Example of documentation of `java.io.File` -

[image]

Comment: Well first of all; the problem is not that it does not show, it does; but rather that, it shows incomplete. I followed your suggestion just in case and checked it off, but I still see the same. I think I'm missing documentation and that's why I only have signatures. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you will have to download the documentation through the SDK Manager, it'll show you documentation somewhat like this, I've updated the answer, check it.

Comment: Still no success. I noticed that your documentation says "Android API 25 Platform" and mine says "1.8(2)" also the method signature starts with "org.jetbrains.anotations..." so probably something is not configured right. I actually installed Android Studio on a different drive and was messing around with some configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. Note that the documentations shows fine for Android code; however, the problem was for the non-android java code.

The screenshot I posted shows the documentations used "<1.8 (2)>". In the file D:\Android.AndroidStudio2.3\config\options\jdk.table.xml I needed the following

```
<javadocPath>
    <root type="composite">
        <root type="simple" url="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/" />
    </root>
</javadocPath>
```

Before it only had this:

```
<javadocPath>
    <root type="composite" />
</javadocPath>
```

Now it shows correctly, I think.

[image]