# Android studio hints

Tags: java, android-studio

How to enable tooltips in android studio when hovering over class or method should show documentation etc like intellij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In intellij is `ctrl + q`

Try in Android studio. If not, go to settings and bind the shortcut.

This question is duplicated: [How to view method information in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619667/how-to-view-method-information-in-android-studio#16619709)