# extended tooltips for Android studio (functions and classes)

Tags: android-studio, tooltip

In Android studio the pop-up code insight tooltip view is very short and I wonder is there any setting that shows more tooltips e.g. some example, usage erc?
[image]

I meant something like `TexStudio` Tooltip that is rather complete:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Press `Ctrl` + Right Click on a function in Android Studio to jump to its source code for more information about that function.
- Type function name then press `Ctrl` + `J` . This will type out all arguments automatically. For example if you type `Toast` then by pressing `Ctrl` + `J` the following autocomplete will appear:

  `Toast.makeText( , "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()`

See also: [How to view method information in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16619667/6576302)